# Concatenate files in subfolders with sox

Tags: bash, audio, terminal, concatenation, sox

I have a folder with subfolders containing wav files I need to concatenate, resulting in 1 wav file per folder.

In each individual folder I can use sox to do: `sox *.wav combined.wav` but I have 1000 folders.

How to I:

a) write a command (using Mac terminal) to concatenate all files within the subfolders for each subfolder?
b) make sure the resulting file has a suitable name e.g. the name of the subfolder?

I have tried to exemplify my file structure below:

e.g.

Audio Files

> 170
>
> > 170_a.wav
> >
> > 170_b.wav
> >
> > 170_c.wav
> >
> > 170_d.wav
>
> 171
>
> > 171_a.wav
> >
> > 171_b.wav
> >
> > 171_c.wav
> >
> > 171_d.wav

etc.

And I would like to end up with 170_combined.wav and 171_combined.wav etc.

Comment: If you run `sox *.wav combined.wav`  It will be automatically renamed as `170_combined.wav` or you need to add the prefix `170_` ?

Comment: It would just name the file "combined.wav" if nothing else was specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `find`

```
find . -type d -exec bash -O nullglob -c 'cd "$0" && files=(*.wav) && ((${#files[@]})) && echo sox "${files[@]}" "${0##*/}_combined.wav"' {} \;
```

- That will not do anything but print the output to `stdout`.
- Remove the `echo` if you think the output is ok, so it will actually convert the files.

A brief explanation.

- `-type d` means find will look for directory only.
- `-exec` is use so we can call/invoke a shell to do a shell tasks.
- `bash -O nullglob` Just in case there are no files the glob `*.wav` will not expand. ( no files will be added to the `array` `files` )
- `-c` Execute a shell commands
- `cd "$0" &&` go inside on each directory `&&` run the next command if the command before it succeeded.
- `files=(*.wav) &&` Create an array of `*.wav` files
- `((${#files[@]}))` If array is not empty ( there are `*.wav` files )
- `sox "${files[@]}" "${0##*/}_combined.wav` Run `sox` on all the `*.wav` files, the `"${0##*/}` strips the filename from the path name.